# How do I handle version with ModeShape JCR?

Tags: jcr, modeshape

I have created a POC program to exercise the JCR version handling with ModeShape on both 4.0.0.Alph4 and 3.8.0.Final. The version number is increased from 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 1.3, 1.4, and etc. Then I restored the version 1.2 and made changes to it. But I noticed that the new version number is 1.3.0 now. Should the new version number be 1.2.0 (since it is based on the original 1.2) or am I missing something from the program? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have expected 1.2.1, so it looks like it might be a bug. Please report the issue in the project's [bug tracker](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/MODE). ModeShape is an open source project, we'll likely look at the issue much more quickly if you provide a simple test case.

But what we really love is a [pull-request](https://github.com/ModeShape/modeshape) that adds to [a test class](https://github.com/ModeShape/modeshape/blob/master/modeshape-jcr/src/test/java/org/modeshape/jcr/JcrVersioningTest.java) one or more test methods that replicates the problem. We can get that pull-request, run the tests (which would fail), and then fix the problem. This *really* saves us a lot of time, and it us know that we're fixing the exact problem you see. And you'll know that the fix will be included in the next release.